# Select GROUP BY column without selecting the Sum() Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Say I have searched multiple sheets with a query and gotten the following table in Google Sheets: *(its nested, so it will never actually be displayed)*

```
     |  Item   | Amount  |   ID   |
     ------------------------------
     |   cat   |    3    |    1   |
     ------------------------------
     |   dog   |    2    |    2   |
     ------------------------------
     |   dog   |    4    |    2   |
     ------------------------------
     |   bird  |    1    |    3   |
     ------------------------------
     |   bird  |    2    |    3   |
     ------------------------------
     |   dog   |    1    |    2   |
     ------------------------------
```

Obviously, If I want to get the Sum of Dogs and Birds from this table I could do something like this:

*(-not exact syntax, just an example)*

```
"SELECT Col1, sum(Col2) WHERE Col1 = 'dog' or 'bird' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Sum(Col2)"
```

And I should get something like the following:

```
      |  Item   | Amount  |
      ---------------------
      |   dog   |    7    |  
      ---------------------
      |   bird  |    3    |  
      ---------------------
```

BUT - Is there a way I can return *ONLY* Col1 *(As in still do the Grouping and ordering)* so that If I was to put it side by side with a result that showed all Columns it would still line up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Solved it!!!  Quite Simple Really....

All I have to do is to add another layer of nesting.

SO:

```
=QUERY(table, "SELECT Col1, sum(Col2) WHERE Col1 = 'dog' or 'bird' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Sum(Col2))"
```

Becomes:

```
    =QUERY(
           QUERY(table, "SELECT Col1, sum(Col2) WHERE Col1 = 'dog' or 'bird' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Sum(Col2)"),
           "SELECT Col1"
            )
```

Again, Syntax not exact, but its the Logic I was after :)

:)

Comment: @pnuts, index usage is a great way to solve this, you may share it as an unswer